# Not able to access the container over localhost

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-run, docker-command

Docker beginner here.

I created a simple asp.net web application , which on run shows me the default page of application.

Using the docker build command, I create a image out of it and further using the docker run command `docker run -d --name {containername} -p 81:8080 {imageid}`. Now when I try to access the container image over local host on browser i.e.  http://localhost:81/, I am getting 'The site cannot be reached' error. I expected the same default page of application to open over the exposed port 81.

My docker client is windows/amd and docker server is linux/amd. The docker version I am using is 19.03.08

Using docker inspect  I could see

```
"PortBindings": {
                "8080/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "81"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

and  "IPAddress": ""  in networksettings.

[docker ps and docker ps -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTDqd.png)

I would appreciate any help or suggestion.

Comment: Does `http://127.0.0.1:81/` work?

Comment: @hmm No, same issue.

Comment: on which port you application is running, I do not think its 8080?

Comment: Are you using Docker Toolbox on Windows, or the Docker Desktop application?  When you start the application, does it print a "listening on..." message?

Comment: @Adiii  and David Maze : After a few changes in Docker file now I am able to get the container in running state. I can see the same(container in running state) in docker desktop. Also, the port 8080 is exposed(see image in link).. Though even now I am getting "The page isn't working. Localhost didn't send any data" error. [link]https://imgur.com/a/JY74TAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screen shots attached, it seems your container is killed as soon as its started. You should have a process running in the container to keep it up & running. Only then will you be able to access via the host ip:port 
In this case `http://localhost:81`

In your `docker ps -a` the status is exited. Ideally it should be something like this if your container is up & running.

```
docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                CREATED              STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
4c01db0b339c        ubuntu:12.04                 bash                   17 seconds ago       Up 16 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the container in running state and is no longer exiting immediately. But when I view it in browser I get "This page isnt working. localhost didnt send any data". https://imgur.com/a/JY74TAL

Comment: Try logging in to your container shell with `docker exec -it containerid bash`  , this will take you into container shell. Try checking your process is running there as expected and try netcat to your container port, `nc -zv localhost 8080`